# Segmentation Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I had created a segmentation algorithm that is able to detect levels above a certain threshold and alternates between 2 categories (red and green) as shown in Figure 1 below. My current algorithm always take reference from the left and detects the first segment as red, followed by green and so on.

However, I would like the algorithm to take reference starting from the center of the longest 0s gap (10-01-06 to 10-01-14) outwards, where the first segment detected on the left will always be green and the first segment detected on the right will always be red. The longest gap can be anywhere and may not always be at the center of the dataset.

I would like the algorithm to return individual list for red and green, with their respective starting and ending point indexes.

I have attached the codes below to replicate the plot.

Figure1:

[image]

```
# Creating Dummy Dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50,100,size=(100, 1)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50,100,size=(100, 1)))
zeros1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(80))
zeros2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(50))
zeros3 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(500))
zeros4 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(80))
zeros5 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(50))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50,100,size=(100, 1)))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(50,100,size=(100, 1)))
df5=pd.concat([zeros1, df, zeros2, df2, zeros3, df3, zeros4, df4, zeros5 ], ignore_index=True)
times = pd.date_range('2012-10-01', periods=len(df5), freq='1min')
df6 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(times), df5], axis = 1, ignore_index=True)

segment = []

for i in range(0,len(df6)):
    if df6.iloc[i,1]> 50:
        segment.append(99)
    else:
        segment.append(0)
        
# Segmentation Algo
state_v,state_p = (0,0) # cycling through states (0,0), (99,0), (0,1), (99,1)
segments = ([],[])
for i,v in enumerate(segment):
    if state_v == 0:
        if v == 99:
            start = i
            state_v = 99
    elif state_v == 99:
        if v == 0:
            end = i
            segments[state_p].append((start, end))
            state_v = 0
            state_p = 1 - state_p
if state_v == 99:
    end = len(segment)
    segments[state_p].append((start, end))

# Plot
door_open, door_close = segments
plt.plot(df6[0], df6[1])

for o in door_open:
    plt.axvline(df6[0][o[0]], linewidth=1, color='r', linestyle= '-')
    plt.axvline(df6[0][o[1]], linewidth=1, color='r', linestyle= '-')
for c in door_close:
    plt.axvline(df6[0][c[0]], linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle= '-')
    plt.axvline(df6[0][c[1]], linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle= '-')
    
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```